# How can I eliminate noise from a switched mode power supply through a laptop?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

The laptop has a metal case, the charger is pulling 240v and outputting 19.5V

When my hand is in contact with the metal case there is no noise coming through the headphones.

If I draw my fingers across the metal case gently I can feel what I can only describe as a vibration.

Is there anything I can add to the case, the charger or the plug (UK 3 pin plug but the earth pin on the charger is plastic, probably because its double insulated.) to remove or reduce the noise?

Comment: Oh! Ungrounded charger. Did it come with the laptop? You can probably ground any exposed metal part of the laptop to your nearest ground point.

Comment: Please see [Laptop surface vibrating because of ungrounded adapter](https://superuser.com/q/1103456/272824).

Comment: Is the mains cable detachable from the charger? If it is, does the charger have a 3 pin grounded mains input socket?

Comment: ground the laptop chassis.

Comment: It's specifically the HP charger that came with it and even the replacement they sent when I complained about it.